# i have been trying to complete the login request to get a capture from the site but always get variable not decleared

Tags: vb.net, variables

```
                    httpRequest.AddParam("u", array(0))
                httpRequest.AddParam("p", array(1))
                Dim string_ As String = httpRequest.Post("https://order.dominos.ca/power/login?rememberMe=false").ToString()
                Dim flag5 As Boolean = string_.Contains("CustomerID")
                If flag5 Then
                    Dim value As String = Form1.smethod_0(string_, "CustomerID"":""", """")
                    Dim UR As String = value + "/loyalty"
                    Dim URL As String = "https://order.dominos.ca/power/customer/" + UR
                    Dim text2 As String = httpRequest.Get(URL).ToString()
                    If Not text2.Contains("VestedPointBalance"":0") Then
                        Dim value2 As String = Form1.smethod_0(string_, "VestedPointBalance"":", ",")
                        If text2 Then
                            value2 = value2
                        End If
                        obj = Me.object_0
                    End If
                    Dim value3 As String = value2
                    Dim flag2 As Boolean = False
                    Try
                            Dim expr_222 As Object = obj
                            obj2 = expr_222
                            Monitor.Enter(expr_222, flag2)
                            array.Resize(Of String)(Me.string_2, Me.int_2 + 1)
                        Me.string_2(Me.int_2) = text + " ------> Points: " + value3
                        Me.int_2 += 1
                            Me.int_5 += 1
                        Me.int_6 -= 1
                        Continue While
                        Finally
```

so i can't debug it because vb always errors "value2" as not declared i tried to put end if after i finish using value2 but didn't work actually i got more errors

Comment: If you know the problem, why have you asked us for help? You either need to move the `value2` declaration out of the `If` statement, or move the following `End If` below pretty much all your code (depending on how you need it to work). If you need help because _no matter what you do_ you get additional errors when changing the code then we need to see exactly what you did and what errors you get, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: You should turn on `Option Strict`.  This line attempts to treat a `String` variable as a `Boolean`:  `If text2 Then`  which makes no sense.